# Generate XML namespace alias attributes for ArrayOfString, from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to use XSLT to inject the following into an .exe.config file:

```
<setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="Xml">
  <value>
    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
    <string>test</string>
  </value>
</setting>
```

To be honest I don't know why the `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` attributes are there, since the xsi and xsd prefixes are not used inside the ArrayOfString element. But this is the XML generated by Visual Studio for a setting of type string array and I want my generated XML to match that.

Here is a cut-down version of the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MySettingsSection>
    </MySettingsSection>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here my closest XSL so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Copy elements by default -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- inject new element at the end of MySettingsSection -->
  <xsl:template match="MySettingsSection">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="setting">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">MySetting</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="serializeAs">Xml</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="value">
          <xsl:element name="ArrayOfString">
            <xsl:attribute namespace="xmlns" name="xmlns:xsi">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute namespace="xmlns" name="xmlns:xsd">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="string">test</xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <applicationSettings>
      <MySettingsSection>
         <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
               <ArrayOfString xmlns:xp_0="xmlns" xp_0:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xp_0:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <string>test</string>
               </ArrayOfString>
            </value>
         </setting>
      </MySettingsSection>
   </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Note the generated xp_0 prefix in the ArrayOfString element (the name of which varies by XSLT engine). I can see that the generated XML is probably *equivalent* to what I want, but I would like the generated `ArrayOfStrings` element to exactly match what I stated at the beginning of the question (this is a config file upgrade scenario).

Why is this happening, and is what I want possible without resorting to quoting the fragment that I want literally?

Comment: Why do you consider "quoting the fragment" as a last resort? Using literal result elements is much easier and preferred to using `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` as those are only needed if you need to compute an element or attribute name and/or namespace. If you want to insert the fragment you have then write a template where you include it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen When I said "quoting the fragment" I was envisaging putting it inside <xsl:text> and having to escape all the < > characters, which would obviously be pretty ugly and would not be checked for validity by the XSLT engine. I hadn't realised that XML elements can be used literally in an XSLT template. Now sorted thanks to Ian Robert's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace declarations are not attributes as far as the XPath data model is concerned, and you can't create them using `xsl:attribute`<sup>1</sup>.  But you don't need to - `<xsl:element>` is only necessary when you need to calculate the name of the element at runtime.  If you already know the name you can just use [literal result elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element) instead of `xsl:element`, and any namespaces declared on a literal result element should percolate through onto the output tree automatically (assuming they haven't already been declared at a higher level).

```
<xsl:template match="MySettingsSection">
  <xsl:copy>
    <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="Xml">
      <value>
        <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        <string>test</string>
      </value>
    </setting>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

<sup>1. you can use [`xsl:namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-namespace-nodes) in XSLT 2.0, but that option isn't available in XSLT 1.0.</sup>